# Force user to use custom init method for the initialization

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a `UIView` subclass with the intention to force users to my required init method than the default one.

So for that, I have created a convenience method for this.

```
@available(*, unavailable, message: "init is unavailable.")
public override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
}

required
convenience public init(withSomeParameters myParam:Type) {
    self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
   //Doing something nice!
}
```

This works! However, when I try to `init` it's showing me two ways to initialize it. How to force the user to make use of custom `init` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make it private , so user must need to  init Test class with `withSomeParameters`

```
class Test:UIView {
    private override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    convenience public init(withSomeParameters myParam:Type) {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        //Doing something nice!
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to mark the coder initialiser as unavailable as well:

```
@available(*, unavailable)
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
  super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

Plus: remove the `convenience` from your initialiser, and call supers `init(frame:)`

```
public init(withSomeParameters myParam:Type) {
  super.init(frame: .zero)
  //Doing something nice!
}
```

As another example, here is some base `UIView` subclass I use in a lot of my projects that don't utilise storyboards:

```
class MXView: UIView {
  init() {
   super.init(frame: .zero)
  }

  //  Storyboards are incompatible with truth and beauty.
  @available(*, unavailable)
  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }
}
```

Subclass:

```
class CustomView: MXView {
  init(someParameters params: Type) {
    // Phase 1: store ivars.

    super.init()

    // Phase 2: Do something nice.
}
```

If you do it like that, users of `CustomView` will be forced to use `init(someParamters:)`. `init(frame:)` is shadowed because `init(someParameters:)` is a non-convenience init.